# PYTHON: How can I call my variable to other function?

Tags: python, function, variables

```
try:                    
    def variables():
        OPERATORS = set(['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '^']) 
        PRIORITY = {'+':1, '-':1, '*':2, '/':2, '^':3}

    def formula1(expression):
    variables()
    stack = []
    output = ''
    for ch in expression:
        if ch not in OPERATORS:
            output+= ch
        elif ch=='(': 
            stack.append('(')
        elif ch==')':   
            while stack and stack[-1]!= '(':    
                output+=stack.pop() 
            stack.pop() 
        else:   
            while stack and stack[-1]!='(' and PRIORITY[ch]<=PRIORITY[stack[-1]]:
                output+=stack.pop()
                stack.append(ch)
        while stack:
            output+=stack.pop()
            return output
    
    expression = input('Enter infix expression: ')
    print('infix expression: ',expression)
    print('postfix expression: ',formula1(expression))
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

**Sample output:**

Enter infix expression: (a+b)

infix expression:  (a+b)

name 'OPERATORS' is not defined

[Program finished]

**I want to call the whole content of the function variables. My task is to do an infix to postfix with 2 functions. But what I did earlier is 1 function only and it works fine. I want to make it 2 functions but I get errors and I don't know how to fix it.**

Comment: You could just keep those variables as global variables right?

Comment: Make them global variables.

Comment: Get rid of this `def variables():`

Comment: sir JacksonB, my task is to make 2 functions with that program :( thats why i made 2 functions but how? Is it possible to do the append or pop in that 2 functions?

Comment: @MarkPauloCruz, I have edited my answer, you asked me to see if it's possible with two functions. If you want to do with two functions then this you can try.

Comment: Please accept the answer and also upvote the answer if it works 

Comment: Hey you haven't accepted the answer still

Answer (score 1):

```py
def variables(): # remove this variables function
OPERATORS = set(['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '^']) 
PRIORITY = {'+':1, '-':1, '*':2, '/':2, '^':3}
```

Remove that function and do the necessary indention.

If you want to make using two functions

```py
try:
    OPERATORS, PRIORITY=None, None                 
    def variables():
        global OPERATORS
        global PRIORITY
        OPERATORS = set(['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '^']) 
        PRIORITY = {'+':1, '-':1, '*':2, '/':2, '^':3}

    def formula1(expression):
    variables()
    stack = []
    output = ''
    for ch in expression:
        if ch not in OPERATORS:
            output+= ch
        elif ch=='(': 
            stack.append('(')
        elif ch==')':   
            while stack and stack[-1]!= '(':    
                output+=stack.pop() 
            stack.pop() 
        else:   
            while stack and stack[-1]!='(' and PRIORITY[ch]<=PRIORITY[stack[-1]]:
                output+=stack.pop()
                stack.append(ch)
        while stack:
            output+=stack.pop()
            return output
    
    expression = input('Enter infix expression: ')
    print('infix expression: ',expression)
    print('postfix expression: ',formula1(expression))
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```